# use of undeclared identifier theos

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

I am developing a tweak, but somehow I get the error:

use of undeclared identifier '_test' error even while the property has set.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *test;
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: can u share its code ?

Comment: It's the code from this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976470/how-to-add-custom-menu-item-to-uitextview-menu-which-is-a-link-to-the-wikipedia

Comment: add that code where you faced this error .

Answer (score 0):

try

in your.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *test;
```

in your.m

```
@implementation Viewcontroller

@synthesize test;
```

and for more informations check this answer [Error: Use of undeclared identifier '_testArray'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918388/why-do-i-need-to-write-synthesize-when-i-provide-getter-and-setter)